# question about closure in js and wrong output

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to understand the core of js concepts, and I tried to write some closure.

```
function counter(){

  let counter = 0;
  
  return{
    increment: () => counter++,
    getCounter:  counter
  }
}


const addCounter = counter();

addCounter.increment();
addCounter.increment();
addCounter.increment();
addCounter.increment();
addCounter.increment();

console.log(addCounter.getCounter)
```

the output here is `0`
if I will change `getCounter:  counter` to `getCounter:()=>counter` and will call again with `addCounter.getCounter()` the answer is correct and will be `5`. can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 2):

When the object is returned, the content here is evaluated as an expression:

```
{
    increment: () => counter++,
    getCounter:  counter
}
```

At that point in time, the `counter` is 0, so it's equivalent to

```
{
    increment: () => counter++,
    getCounter: 0
}
```

The `counter`, although updated by the `increment` function, is not referenced again after the (static) object is returned.

You need to make `getCounter` a function or getter, so that it returns the current value inside the closure.

```js
function counter(){

  let counter = 0;
  
  return{
    increment: () => counter++,
    get getCounter() { return counter; }
  }
}


const addCounter = counter();

addCounter.increment();
addCounter.increment();
addCounter.increment();
addCounter.increment();
addCounter.increment();

console.log(addCounter.getCounter)
```